# Connecting android client with oracle server

Tags: java, android, oracle, plsql

I need to connect *over the internet* with the Android client to Oracle PL/SQL database. (With static ip or with the host name).

But already using java client over the year with oracle. And I **don't want to go for another database** for implementing (*Because I already written most **complex** procedures.,*)

And that java client server connection happening via **LAN** connections only (*But the system has the static ip and **not used for this**. Because LAN communication works perfectly*).

Please tell me the process what I have to take.

**Note:** I am using Oracle 10g (**10.2.0.5.0**) and Latest Version of java (**1.8**).

**If Possible:** Please Provide a link for ojdbc drivers(*Don't know which driver version used for Android*).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PL/SQL is the procedural language used in an Oracle Database... it is not a database of itself.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the appropriate place to ask for a tutorial - either ask a specific question about JDBC drivers (and remove all the ancillary comments) or focus your question on the code you have tried and the issues you have had.